# What should I do when I find a major mistake for a top conference paper?

Tags: conference

Most new results are presented on the conferences in computer science. Are there some suggestions when I find a major mistake for a paper?

Comment: Paper that's already published?  Paper you're currently refereeing?  Paper of which you're an author?